# Scikit-learn: NameError: name 'load_iris' is not defined

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I got the error message of scikit-learn: iris database = load_iris () and after I get the error :NameError: name 'load_iris' is not defined

What could be the problem? Help me please!

I use :
Phyton 3.9.5
Anaconda 4.10.1
Scikit-learn 2.2.0

Comment: Hello, can you copy and paste the script that you are executing? Perhaps by taking a look into the code we can identify the error.

Comment: did you import `load_iris` function?

Comment: from sklearn import datasets

Comment: from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

Comment: import numpy as np

Comment: from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

Comment: iris_database = load_iris()

Answer (score 1):

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

iris = load_iris()

print(iris.data)
print(iris.target)
```

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_iris.html

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You have to import `load_iris` first. Try this:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris_dataset = load_iris()
print("Keys of iris_dataset: \n{}".format(iris_dataset.keys()))
print("iris_datasets[DESCR][:193]+\n. . . ")
```

You can display the target names, feature names, etc.. the same way.